# How to override form validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

How do I write a function that overrides form validation when a user clicks the back button?

If the user doesn't fill the form and clicks submit, it tells shows **" please fill in this field"**
then I added a back button in case the user doesn't wanna fill the form and wants to go back
but onClick it shows "please fill in this field"

how do I override this when the user clicks back?

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}

function goBack() {
  window.history.back()
}
```

```html
<div class="form-div">
  <form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" required>
    <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="name"><b>FullName</b></label>
      <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="fullName" id="name" required>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>
      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="psw" name="psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required>
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
      <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container signin">
      <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>` is ALSO a submit button. Make it type="button" or move it outside the form

Comment: I moved it outside the form and it stopped responding
onClick it doesn't do anything

Comment: That is highly unlikely

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the "required" attribute from your form tag should be good even if you keep this "required" attribute on your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This thing happen because you added button inside `<form>` that causing it to act as a submit button
see this: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

so basically you can return `false`, but its much easer to just remove the button outside the `<form>`

**FYI**
You should **ALWAYS** check the values of the inputs buy yourself because everyone who is familiar with the devTools can delete the `required` attribute and then send empty values to your server

**Another FYI** 
You must check the values also in the server because there are many ways you can override the client checks (you do the client side check just for UX)

Comment: how do I do the latter?
The checking